# Rubis on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

GoogleAppEngine is a PaaS service and I doubt if it would allow me to setup an environment for Rubis installation. But it is best to verify here, so is it possible to install Rubis (http://rubis.ow2.org/doc/index.html) on GoogleAppEngine?

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that. Rubis requires EBJ, JOnAS and uses MySQL. To my knowledge, you cannot run any "persistent" applications using GAE. For the persistence layer, you have to use specific API such as BigTables.

To sum up, Rubis could run on GAE, but it would require a significant porting effort.